# Changing elements in multi-dimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays

Inside arrays, I have `0`s and one `1`.

```
class Image
  def initialize(rows)
    @rows = rows
  end
end

image = Image.new([
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
])
```

I want the numbers that are located up, down, left, and right to turn `1` as well. I tried to do this by manipulating `column_index` and `row_index`. The code is:

```
class Image
  def blur
    @rows_copy = Array.new(@rows.size) {Array.new(@rows.first.size)}
    @rows.each_with_index do |row, row_index|
      row.each_with_index do |cell, column_index|
        blur_location(row_index,column_index)
      end
    end
    @rows = @rows_copy
  end
  def blur_location (row_index, column_index)
    if @rows[row_index][column_index] == 1
      @rows_copy[row_index][column_index] = 1
      @rows_copy[row_index + 1][column_index] = 1
      @rows_copy[row_index - 1][column_index] = 1
      @rows_copy[row_index][column_index + 1] = 1
      @rows_copy[row_index][column_index - 1] = 1
    else
      @rows_copy[row_index][column_index] = 0
    end
  end
  def output_image
    @rows.each_with_index do |row, row_index|
      puts row.join('')
    end
  end
end

image.blur
image.output_image
```

But only half of the code is working (i.e., the top and left turns to `1`, but not the other two).

Comment: This question was [asked recently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28777194/two-dimensional-array-with-ruby/28777829#28777829).  I think using the [Matrix](http://ruby-doc.org//stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) class is the way to go, but not everyone would agree.

Answer (score 1):

the code almost works as expected but you are a victim of the following piece of code:

```
else
  @rows_copy[row_index][column_index] = 0
end
```

What happens is the when you hit the '1' you set everything as expected, but when you move on and you hit the zeros that are near the '1' (to the right and down as you're processing) you are resetting the rows_copy to zero.

Here is a revised version of the code the does the right thing (notice how the copy is all first set to 0 and after that only 1s are marked):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Image
  def initialize(rows)
    @rows = rows
  end

  def blur
    @rows_copy = Array.new(@rows.size) {Array.new(@rows.first.size)}
    @rows.each_with_index do |row, row_index|
      row.each_with_index do |cell, column_index|
        set_zero(row_index,column_index)
      end
    end
    @rows.each_with_index do |row, row_index|
      row.each_with_index do |cell, column_index|
        blur_location(row_index,column_index)
      end
    end
    @rows = @rows_copy
  end
  def set_zero(row_index, column_index)
     @rows_copy[row_index][column_index] = 0
  end
  def blur_location (row_index, column_index)
    if @rows[row_index][column_index] == 1
      @rows_copy[row_index][column_index] = 1
      @rows_copy[row_index + 1][column_index] = 1
      @rows_copy[row_index - 1][column_index] = 1
      @rows_copy[row_index][column_index + 1] = 1
      @rows_copy[row_index][column_index - 1] = 1
    end
  end
  def output_image
    @rows.each_with_index do |row, row_index|
      puts row.join('')
    end
  end
end

image = Image.new([
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
])

image.blur
image.output_image
```